# Overview of all available Quick Link' web-part icons for Sharepoine Online modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, quick-links

SPO has loads of built-in icons, I've already added a web-part to my modern page and utilised a number of O365 icons.  I've been adding these one at a time to the web-part on my page and am pleased with the result (see picture).

What I'd like to do is make a sort of reference guide for me, as SharePoint Admin, to use. Perhaps I could configure a list, so I can filter on it, of all available built-in icons.  Is this somehow possible?

I'd rather avoid making a page and having to manually add each icon individually, because it'd take too long and I couldn't filter on it.

[image: Quick Link Web-part icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to below web site for icons:

[Office UI Fabric Icons](https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/)

You can see, search/filter all available icons on above web page like:

[image]

Also, you can copy friendly name/Unicode of icon by right clicking on it:

[image]